# Why is my weight-gain supplement causing unexpected abdomen growth?

Tags: weight-loss, workout-routines, gym, abdominals, supplements

I am asking this question on behalf of my friend. He says he has been regularly going to gym and doing workouts for 3 months for 1 and half hours daily, which consist of push-ups, leg-raises, dumbbell lifting, deadlifting, etc, which has shaped his body and also helped him to gain 4kg of weight which surely reflects in his physical structure. But somehow his tummy is protruding as well.

He regularly consumes Optimum Nutrition (ON) Serious Mass  due to his lean slim body structure.

Please let me know if these section is the right place to ask. If not then let me know, and I can delete it.

Comment: [Nutrition unrelated to exercise](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is off topic on this site.

Comment: @rrirower - It's not really unrelated. He gives his exercise routine, and the base question is "why is my tummy coming out". The nutrition is adjunctive, not central (IMO, anyway).

Comment: @JohnP I would normally agree except for the question title.  It seems more geared toward asking why his supplement is not working the way he expects it to.  And, less about how it works with his training.

Comment: @rrirower - Yes, it is misleading. I have considered editing it, I still may.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, [men can expect to gain up to about half a pound of muscle per week](http://www.aworkoutroutine.com/how-much-muscle-can-you-gain/), which is about .25 kg per week. This means one can expect about 6 pounds (or just under 3 kg) of muscle gained in three months. *Under optimal circumstances*.  Most people don't train, eat, or recover optimally, which means 6 pounds may be slightly over optimistic.

This means the excess weight gained is due to water, bodily waste products, and increased fat mass. All of those can contribute to a larger looking midsection. The fact that your friend is using a mass gainer means he's consuming a large amount of carbs which also tend to cause water retention. I suspect a good portion of their 4 kg weight gain is at least water weight and increased fat with a minority of it being muscle.

Comment: So, what should a person follow! Should he No take supplements  for gaining weight? Can it be possible to  do more workout  and converting carbs to build more muscle? or he must follow protein diet?

Answer (score 1):

Is he experiencing more muscle there?  More fat? Is it just not going away as fast as he'd like? My gut reaction, no pun intended, is that he's taking in more calories than he's burning, which is resulting in weight gain. As to why it's the abdomen, well, you can't target fat-loss or gain. He should probably start charting out his calories consumed to make sure that his bulking powder isn't providing too many calories in addition what he's already eating.

If it's muscle, he may want to cut back on exercises that focus on his stomach and abdomen in favor of exercising the rest of the body in hopes of at least hiding what he has in favor of other muscle.

Comment: more fat in abdomen, but muscle are growing for sure in his arms and shoulder.

Comment: Ah. So most likely he's just taking in too many calories overall, so the excess is converting to fat and he just happens to be someone who gains most of their weight at the abdomen.